# Boost log rotation doesn't take account in existing file size

Tags: logging, boost, rotation, filesize

I want to rotate the log when a single log file size exceeds 10MB. My application is not a long-running process, it is invoked by other programs periodically, so the total log file size will increase. However, I noticed the log file rotation doesn't take the previous log file size into account. For example, if the existing file size is already 11MB, and I keep appending new logs to it, let's say 1kb each run of my app, then the file will never rotate. Only if I write more than 10MB logs in a single run of my application, then the log can rotate.

I have attached my configuration code below. Is this the desired behavior of boost log? Can I configure it to take the existing file size into account? Because our application need to rotate log based on accumulated log size.

```
auto sink = logging::add_file_log(
                            logging::keywords::file_name = logFilePath,
                            logging::keywords::target_file_name = rotationLogFilePath,
                            logging::keywords::open_mode = std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::app,
                            logging::keywords::rotation_size = 10 * 1024 * 1024,
                            logging::keywords::max_size = 30 * 1024 * 1024,
                            logging::keywords::max_files = 3,
                            logging::keywords::target = file_dir,
                            logging::keywords::scan_method = logging::sinks::file::scan_matching,
                            logging::keywords::enable_final_rotation = false);
sink->locked_backend()->auto_flush(true);
```

Comment: You may be affected by https://github.com/boostorg/log/issues/151.

Comment: @AndreySemashev Thanks, it solved my issue by setting std::ios_base::ate.
One more question: I'm using wildcard name "FileName.log.%N%" for the above config, but the number N in my log file name keeps increasing, I want my log file names to always be FileName.log, FileName.log.1 and FileName.log.2, is there a way to do that?

Comment: No, the library does not rename the previously rotated files.